# Failed to create directory or subvolume "/var/run/celery": Permission denied

Tags: systemd

I'm trying to create folders in `/var/run` for pids for celery processes.

I've created (as root) a `celery.conf` file at `/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/celery.conf` containing only the following line:

```
D /var/run/celery 0755 myuser mygroup -
```

However, when I run `systemd-tmpfiles --create` I get:

`Failed to create directory or subvolume "/var/run/celery": Permission denied`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this out while writing the question: `systemd-tmpfiles` needs to be run as root.